# Android app process not killed after removed from recent app list

Tags: android, service, process

I found my app's process is not killed after I swipe away from recently used app list, but only happen on LG nexus 5 with Android OS 6.0.1 (from devices I've tested), the process is killed cleanly on other devices.

I've integrated a third party sdk which would start other processes and services if I init it and I'm sure it's related because if I don't init it, the problem disappears, but I'm not clear how and what flags the third party uses when creating those services.

So my question is, is there any known bugs or system-wise settings I'm missing that cause this behaves differently in different devices or OS?

Answer (score 2):

Apps are not stopped completely if you swipe the app off the Recent App list. I think services are kept alive if you do this. If you're using a third party then it starts a service for its tasks, then that must be it.